# Why are "dot diagrams" used instead of Young diagrams when teaching the Jordan canonical form?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, math-history, integer-partitions

The Jordan canonical form of a matrix $A$ assigns a partition $p_\lambda$ of $n_\lambda$ to each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, where $n_\lambda$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda$ in the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Most undergradute-level textbooks on linear algebra record $p_\lambda$ using a "dot diagram", which is like a Young diagram but transposed and using dots instead of boxes.  Does anyone know why this notation is preferred or where it came from? Is there any good reason to use it (other than tradition)? Young diagrams have the advantage that you can easily label the boxes, which comes up when explaining how to compute a Jordan basis.

I actually only have one printed example: *Linear Algebra* by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence. But I've heard that, for example, dot diagrams were also used in linear algebra courses in Sofia Univeristy in the 80s, and I think they are widespread.

Comment: "dot diagram"= Ferrer diagram?

Comment: I had forgotten they were called that! But yes, I think so. There is still a difference in that the Ferrers diagrams are drawn as the conjugate of the usual diagram, so that 3+2 is represented by a column of length 3 and a column of length 2.

Comment: What you mention is the dual of the partition. There is a paper by Helen Shapiro that explains the difference in between the Segre and the Weyr characteristic. You are talking about this difference. See https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589746?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

Comment: Thanks for the reference! But it still doesn't quite answer my question. Friedberg et al. explain how to classify the action on a generalized eigenspace by the Segre characteristic, but they then describe this with a Ferrer diagram for the *dual* partition (in the usual convention on Ferrer diagrams, that is). Why is there an extra dual there?

Comment: It may be that there is no satisfying answer to my question: it's not clear whether this is just a different notation (rows instead of columns) or that at some point the description was in terms of the Weyr characteristic and this was changed, but the diagram notation was not changed to match.

Comment: In page 80  "An introduction to the theory of Canonical Matrices" Aitken and Turnball(which is th e oldest concise source I could find in english) seem to introduce the two concepts together in the diagram. I suspect that the presentation is just of Friedberg is pedagogical.